# Fetch every nth row with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We have a table in our SQL database with historical raw data I need to create charts from. We access the DB via Entity Framework and LINQ.

For smaller datetime intervals, I can simply read the data and generate the charts:

```
var mydata = entity.DataLogSet.Where(dt => dt.DateTime > dateLimit);
```

But we want to implement a feature where you can quickly "zoom out" from the charts to include larger date intervals (last 5 days, last month, last 6 months, last 10 years and so on and so forth.)

We don't want to chart every single data point for this. We want to use a sample of the data, by which I mean something like this --

- **Last 5 days**: chart every data point in the table
- **Last month**: chart every 10th data point in the table
- **Last 6 months**: chart every 100th data point

The number of data points and chart names are only examples. What I need is a way to pick only the "nth" row from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that includes the item index of enumerations. Something like this should do the trick --

```
var data = myDataLogEnumeration.
        Select((dt,i) => new { DataLog = dt, Index = i }).
        Where(x => x.Index % nth == 0).
        Select(x => x.DataLog);
```

If you need to limit the query with a **Where** or sort with **OrderBy**, you must do it *before* the first **Select**, otherwise the indexes will be all wrong --

```
var data = myDataLogEnumeration.
        Where(dt => dt.DateTime > dateLimit).
        OrderBy(dt => dt.SomeField).
        Select((dt,i) => new { DataLog = dt, Index = i }).
        Where(x => x.Index % nth == 0).
        Select(x => x.DataLog);
```

Unfortunately, as [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) commented, this overload is not supported in Entity Framework. One way to deal with this is to do something like this --

```
var data = entity.DataLogSet.
        Where(dt => dt.DateTime > dateLimit).
        OrderBy(dt => dt.SomeField).
        ToArray().
        Select((dt,i) => new { DataLog = dt, Index = i }).
        Where(x => x.Index % nth == 0).
        Select(x => x.DataLog);
```

Note the addition of a `ToArray()`. This isn't ideal though as it will force loading all the data that matches the initial query *before* selecting only every nth row.

Comment: But that will fetch every single row, won't it? To count the index, I mean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. No, it will not *fetch* every row. You need to limit your query by using a `Where` before accessing the index. It will *return* only every nth row though.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe EF supports that overload.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instead of ToArray(), use ToEnumerable().  This way the logic above ToEnumerable will be executed as SQL on the server, and the logic underneath the ToEnumerable() will be executed in memory (Linq to Objects).  Since Entity Framework now streams results by default, you won't have to materialize all of the data in memory before sampling +

Answer (score 0):

There might be a trick that is supported by ef that might work for this.

```
if (step != 0)
  query = query.Where(_ => Convert.ToInt32(_.Time.ToString().Substring(14, 2)) % step == 0);
```

this code converts the date into string then cuts the minutes out converts the minutes into an int and then gets every x'th minute for example if the variable step is 5 it's every 5 minutes.

For Postgresql this converts to:

```
WHERE ((substring(c.time::text, 15, 2)::INT % @__step_1) = 0)
```

this works best with fixed meassure points such as once a minute.

However, you can use the same method to group up things by cutting up to the hour or the minutes or the first part of the minute (10 minutes grouped) and use aggregation functions such as max() average() sum(), what might even is more desirable.
For example, this groups up in hours and takes the max of most but the average of CPU load:

```
using var ef = new DbCdr.Context();
IQueryable<DbCdr.CallStatsLog> query;

query = from calls in ef.Set<DbCdr.CallStatsLog>()
        group calls by calls.Time.ToString().Substring(0, 13)
        into g
        orderby g.Max(_ => _.Time) descending
        select new DbCdr.CallStatsLog()
        {
            Time = g.Min(_ => _.Time),
            ConcurrentCalls = g.Max(_ => _.ConcurrentCalls),
            CpuUsage = (short)g.Average(_ => _.CpuUsage),
            ServerId = 0
        };

var res = query.ToList();
```

translates to:

```
 SELECT MAX(c.time) AS "Time",
 MAX(c.concurrent_calls) AS "ConcurrentCalls",
 AVG(c.cpu_usage::INT::double precision)::smallint AS "CpuUsage",
 0 AS "ServerId" 
 FROM call_stats_log AS c                                                                                                                                                                                          
 GROUP BY substring(c.time::text, 1, 13)                                                                                                                                                                           
 ORDER BY MAX(c.time) DESC
```

note: the examples work with postgres and iso datestyle.