# How to fetch every nth row using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on `WEB API`. In my controller, I have created a `method` which takes two parameters `meter serial number` and `date time`. This method is then called in an `API`.

```
  public HttpResponseMessage GetDetails(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = giveCount(msn, dt);

            int interval = count / 500;

          //TODO......

         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {details = interval });// actuall output will be different, for now I am just testing it.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

In above code, there is `count` and then `interval`. Let assume the count is `10000` then `10000/500` will be `20`. So the interval is 20 and I want to fetch single record after every 20th record starting from `1st`. The query is below

```
var prodDetails = mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.sjsj >= dt)
                  .Select(x => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd })
                  .ToList();
```

I have also seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43943402/8919244) but still unable to get my desired result.

How can I set my query that will give results based on the interval?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note:** interval value is not fixed.

Comment: var prodDetails = mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.sjsj >= dt)
                  .Select((x,i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
                  .Where(x => (x.i % 20) == 0)
                  .ToList();

Comment: Consider using MoreLinq's `TakeEvery` https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/ https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeEvery.cs

Comment: @jdweng it works but I am getting multiple values of same record.

Comment: @jdweng this is my output `{ "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 0 }, { "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 24 }, { "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 48 },` same record keeps on

Comment: What are you calling duplicates?  They are not duplicates since the i value is different.  The time is different but you are not seeing it since it is very small.  A ping is usually repeated 3 to 5 times.  You can use GroupBy to combine the Pings.

Comment: @jdweng no in this system the ping is not repeated 3 to 5 times. Ping value can repeat but time is changed. As after 2 minutes new ping will come so they are duplicates.

Comment: Why do you need every 20 item.  Don't you just want to group by MSN?  Using the 20th entry may change and the order may not be consistent.

Comment: I need data after some `nth` interval that's why I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Using your linked solution, you could do this:

```
var prodDetails = mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.sjsj >= dt)
    .Select((x, i) => new { Prod = new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd }, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Index % interval == 0)
    .Select(x => x.Prod)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i am getting this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` works for me but I am getting multiple values of same record

Comment: this is my output `{ "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 0 }, { "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 24 }, { "MSN": "002999001180", "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52", "PingValue": "19", "i": 48 },`